# How To Fix Size Of Gridview in VB.NET?

Tags: gridview, size

How To Fix Size Of Gridview in VB.NET ?
while project is run and click on Edit link button in Gridview to edit column , size of Gridview is lvery large so that size of pages Commix
What's the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question clearly, but if your problem is about loading a lots of rows in GridView, you  can use GridView Paging feature, consider this link:

[Effective-Paging-with-GridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125541/Effective-Paging-with-GridView-Control-in-ASP-NET)